# Need to get total for Column in R

Tags: r, sum

I have done the code up to this point, but have a column called score where I have to add the total together in the rscores tibble.

```
library(tidyverse)
responses <- read_csv("responses.csv")
qformats <- read_csv("qformats.csv")
scoring <- read_csv("scoring.csv")
rlong <- gather(responses,Question, Response, Q1:Q10)
rlong_16 <- filter(rlong, Id == 16)
rlong2 <- inner_join(rlong_16, qformats, by = "Question")
rscores <- inner_join(rlong_2, scoring)
```

What line of code do I add next to get the total for this column? I have been scratching my head for hours. Any help is appreciated :)

```
> head(rscores)
# A tibble: 6 x 5
     Id Question Response            QFormat Score
  <dbl> <chr>    <chr>               <chr>   <dbl>
1    16 Q1       Slightly Disagree   F           0
2    16 Q2       Definitely Agree    R           0
3    16 Q3       Slightly Disagree   R           1
4    16 Q4       Definitely Disagree R           1
5    16 Q5       Slightly Agree      R           0
6    16 Q6       Slightly Agree      R           0
```

Comment: I have tried that and keep getting errors, i don't know if I'm using the right lay out to the line of code. I have only started using R yesterday as it is required for an assignment and I am completely lost haha.

Comment: > head(rscores)
# A tibble: 6 x 5
     Id Question Response            QFormat Score
  <dbl> <chr>    <chr>               <chr>   <dbl>
1    16 Q1       Slightly Disagree   F           0
2    16 Q2       Definitely Agree    R           0
3    16 Q3       Slightly Disagree   R           1
4    16 Q4       Definitely Disagree R           1
5    16 Q5       Slightly Agree      R           0
6    16 Q6       Slightly Agree      R           0

Comment: sorry! put it in

Answer (score 1):

`colSums()` is overkill if you just need the sum of *one* column, and it will give you an error if any other column in the tibble/data.frame/etc. is not convertible to numeric. In you case, there's at least one character (`chr`) column that can't be summed. Typically you'd use `rowSums` or `colSums` on a matrix as opposed to a data frame.

Just use `sum` function on the one column: `sum(rscores$Score)`. Best of luck.